Як ліпше перекласти "can never truly be said"?
Прошу допомогти порадою, як ліпше перекласти "can never truly be said"
Повне речення:  demobilisation can never truly be said to have ended

Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language SE! Щоб зробити відповіді кориснішими додайте більше деталей у ваше питання: які варіанти ви вже розглядали та чому вони вас не влаштовують. Дякую!

Може ніколи не можна правдиво сказати, що демобілізація завершилась

Повне речення в оригіналі виглядає ось так: "According to an extensive survey of hundreds of British Second World War veterans conducted in 2001, one in five is continuing to display war-related psychological distress. ‘I used to be easy-going,’ says one ex-Fe-Pow today, ‘but when I came back I was withdrawn and used to cry at the least thing. It still comes back. I can still cry at anything that brings back memories. I don’t think you can get rid of it. For such men, demobilisation can never truly be said to have ended – because the war has never ended‘."
Що у вільному перекладі може звучати: "Згідно з обширним опитуванням сотень британських ветеранів Другої світової війни, проведеним у 2001 році, кожен п’ятий продовжує демонструвати психологічний стрес, пов’язаний з війною. «Раніше я був легким на підйом», — каже сьогодні один колишній військовополонений: «та коли повернувся, я став замкнутий і сльози наверталися з найменшого приводу. Це досі повторюється. Я все ще можу заплакати через будь-яку дрібницю, яка навіює спогади. Не думаю, що від цього можна позбутися. Для таких чоловіків демобілізація ніколи не стане справжнім фіналом, бо війна ніколи не закінчувалася»".

Щиро дякую, Романе, дуже корисна відповідь
